# Split a list into sublist based on element types in scala

Tags: list, scala

How to split a list into sublist based on element types?

In short, given:

```
trait Drink
final case object Coke extends Drink
final case object Pepsi extends Drink

val drinks = List(Coke,Coke,Pepsi,Coke,Pepsi,Pepsi)
```

I want:

```
List( List(Coke,Coke), List(Pepsi), List(Coke), List(Pepsi, Pepsi) )
```

Comment: Do you want something generic or are you fine with a solution for a particular set of types? Also, will they always be **case objects** or there could also be **case classes**? - Finally, what have you tried?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez this particular set of types is irrelevant. Real world will be case classes.

Comment: Will those case classes would be parametric / generic? Like `final case class Foo[T](data: T) extends Bar` ? If so, and you have `List(Foo(1), Foo("3"))` should those two be in the same group or in different ones?

Comment: Yes, absolutely, I've just not made them parametric to simplify the question

Comment: Well then, your problem is basically unsolvable due to type-erasure. - You have four options: 1. Simplify your data types so that you can avoid type-erasure - 2. Rely only on class tests, which means that both `Foo(1)` and `Foo("3")` will be in the same group - 3. Use **TypeTags** but that would require that whoever is creating the **List** zips each element with its **TypeTag**. - 4. Similar to the previous one, create your own `Type` **ADT** and zip each element with its `Type` when creating the **List**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    drinks.foldRight[List[List[Drink]](List.empty) {
       case (next, (l@(last :: _) :: tail) if next.getClass == last.getClass => 
          (next :: l)::tail
       case (next, rest) => List(next) :: rest
    }
```

If types are parametric you'll need `TypeTags` as mentioned in the comment ... but at that point, it's really going to be easier to just add a method to the class itself ... something like:

```
    class Drink[T: ClassTag] {
       def typeId = s"Drink of ${classTag[T].runtimeClass.getName}"
    }
```

Then you can just compare these type ids rather than actual classes.

Answer (score 1):

```
drinks.foldRight(List.empty[List[Drink]]){
  case (c:Coke.type, ((hd:Coke.type)::tl)::acc)  => (c::hd::tl)::acc
  case (p:Pepsi.type,((hd:Pepsi.type)::tl)::acc) => (p::hd::tl)::acc
  case (d, acc) => List(d)::acc
}
```

Somewhat verbose partly due to them being case objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a short tail-recursive function such as the following.

The idea is to use `next` to store the "next List of Drinks to append to the result" and `acc` to accumulate these Lists of Drinks, into a List of List of Drinks.

The base case is an empty list, in which the results are returned. Otherwise, either the next drink matches the next sublist (add it to this sublist), or it doesn't (add the sublist to the result and start a new sublist with the new drink).

Note that `:+` is a List method which gives back a new List with the specified item appended.

```scala
@tailrec
def get(list:List[Drink],
        next:List[Drink]=List(),
        acc: List[List[Drink]]=List()): List[List[Drink]] =
  list match {
    case Nil => acc :+ next   // dump final results
    case head :: tail =>
      if (next.isEmpty || next.head.getClass == head.getClass) get(tail, next :+ head, acc)
      else get(tail, List(head), acc :+ next)
  }


println(get(drinks))
```

Result:

```
List(List(Coke, Coke), List(Pepsi), List(Coke), List(Pepsi, Pepsi))
```

Note, noticed that jwvh has a correct answer too, with proper pattern matching instead of these conditionals. Using the `head` method on a List can be unsafe (or hard for the compiler to determine the safety), but this approach may be more concise especially if there are many kinds of Drink.

If you want to avoid using `head` directly, you can write this, which I find more confusing:

```scala
...
      if (next.headOption.map(h => h.getClass == head.getClass).getOrElse(true)) get(tail, next :+ head, acc)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't use just `groupBy` on your list?

```
val rows = drinks.groupBy(x => x).values.toList
```

Can test [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/AlleXyS90/t6TlH9aAQqOcKiEnul2Kmw/10)

Comment: This is not what OP asked and it would only even work with `case object`